# Convergence and integral

Tags: integration

Show that if $f_n \to f$ uniformly on `[a, b]`, then $\int_a^b f_n \to \int_a^b f$ when $n \to \infty$.

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your thoughts.

Comment: For now, I am thinking of working with the distance that shows the uniform convegence of $f_n$ in [a, b]. ($lim_{n \to \infty}d_{sup} (f_n, f) = 0$)

Comment: You are required to show that $| \int f_n - \int f| \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. Start out with the expression $| \int f_n - \int f|$ and use properties of integrals and the assumption that $f_n \to f$ uniformly.

Comment: Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Note that $|\int f - \int f_n| \le \int |f-f_n|$.

Comment: yes, I used that, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me combine the suggestions in the comment and write a rather complete answer.

First, you should check the issue that if $f_n$ is integrable, by uniform continuity, its limit $f$ is also integrable.

Then apply the useful estimate @copper.hat mentioned. $$\left|\int_{a}^{b}f_n-\int_{a}^{b}f\right|\leq\int_{a}^{b}|f_n-f|$$

By uniform convergence, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. for all $n\ge N$, $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\frac{\varepsilon}{b-a}$$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. By the above results, for all $n\ge N$, $$\left|\int_{a}^{b}f_n-\int_{a}^{b}f\right|\leq\int_{a}^{b}|f_n-f|<\varepsilon$$
Done.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! :) It was very useful

Comment: You are welcome. Make sure you include your efforts in your future posts, otherwise they will be downvoted.

Comment: Perfect, it's noted! :)